# Retain XMLGregorianCalendar date format after converting to JSON - Jackson Lib

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object that has 2 XMLGregorianCalendar objects - one is used for date and other is used for time. I use Jackson object mapper to convert the date in JSON format. The date before converting is 2014-02-10 & time is 11:15:00. After converting to JSON , it becomes {"date":1392008400000,"time":58500000}. How can I retain the same date & time format ({"date":2014-02-10,"time":11:15:00}) after printing in JSON. .

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;


public class TestJSON {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Date dob=null;
        Date time=null;
        DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        DateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        try {
            dob=df.parse("2014-02-10");
            time=df1.parse("11:15:00");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println(" Date = " + dob);
        System.out.println(" Time = " + time);

        GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        try {
            cal.setTime(df.parse("2014-02-10"));
            cal1.setTime(df1.parse("11:15:00"));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
        XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate1 = null;
        try {
            xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            xmlDate1 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarTime(cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR),cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE),cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
        } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(" Before Converting - Date " + xmlDate);
        System.out.println(" Before Converting - Time " + xmlDate1);

        Data data = new Data();
        data.setDate(xmlDate);
        data.setTime(xmlDate1);



        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        try {
            System.out.println("After Converting " + mapper.writeValueAsString(data));
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}




import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Data {

    private XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    private XMLGregorianCalendar time;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(XMLGregorianCalendar time) {
        this.time = time;
    }



}
```

**WORKING CODE (With Mixins)**

```
    import java.text.DateFormat;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.Calendar;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

    import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
    import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
    import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
    import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

    import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;


    public class TestJSON {

        public static void main(String[] args){

            Date dob=null;
            Date time=null;
            DateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            DateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
            try {
                dob=df.parse("2014-02-10");
                time=df1.parse("11:15:00");
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(" Date = " + dob);
            System.out.println(" Time = " + time);

            GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
            GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
            try {
                cal.setTime(df.parse("2014-02-10"));
                cal1.setTime(df1.parse("11:15:00"));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate = null;
            XMLGregorianCalendar xmlDate1 = null;
            try {
                xmlDate = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarDate(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1, cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
                xmlDate1 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendarTime(cal1.get(Calendar.HOUR),cal1.get(Calendar.MINUTE),cal.get(Calendar.SECOND), DatatypeConstants.FIELD_UNDEFINED);
            } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(" Before Converting - Date " + xmlDate);
            System.out.println(" Before Converting - Time " + xmlDate1);

            Data data = new Data();
            data.setDate(xmlDate);
            data.setTime(xmlDate1);



            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            try {
                mapper.addMixIn(Data.class, MyMixin.class);
                System.out.println("After Converting " + mapper.writeValueAsString(data));

            } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    }


import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Data {

    private XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    private XMLGregorianCalendar time;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(XMLGregorianCalendar time) {
        this.time = time;
    }



}



import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;

public interface MyMixin {

    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDate(); 
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mm:ss")
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getTime();

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here

```
System.out.println(" Date = " + dob);
System.out.println(" Time = " + time);
```

you're printing a `Date` object formatted through its `toString()` method.

Here

```
System.out.println(" Before Converting " + xmlDate);
```

you're printing an `XMLGregorianCalendar` object formatted through its `toString()` method.

Here

```
System.out.println("After Converting " + mapper.writeValueAsString(xmlDate));
```

you're printing a `String` which represents a `XMLGregorianCalendar` converted to a JSON value through `ObjectMapper`'s default conversion, which simply takes the timestamp (time in millis since epoch).

**None of these things are the same.**

If you want your `ObjectMapper` to serialize date types differently, use its [`ObjectMapper#setDateFormat(DateFormat)`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#setDateFormat-java.text.DateFormat-) method as required.

There's also [`SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializationFeature.html#WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS) which is enabled by default.

Comment: Thx Sotirios! I have come up with this program to isolate the problem that I am facing as part of a larger project. I am consuming an external service and converting it to JSON by passing the object returned to ObjectMapper. This large payload has 1 element for date and other for time as specified above. I want to return the date and time in the same format as received from my service. When I use ObjectMapper#setDateFormat() , it gets applied to both date and time elements. I want date to be formatted as "MM-DD-YYY" and do not want time part and I want time to be "hh:mm:ss". I updated the code

Comment: I used mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false) and I see {"date":"2014-02-10T05:00:00.000+0000","time":"1970-01-01T16:15:00.000+0000"}. However I would like {"date":2014-02-10,"time":11:15:00}.

Comment: @PunterVicky You've kind of completely changed your question. Just annotate your fields with `JsonSerialize` and provide a custom `JsonSerializer` for each, one that write the date, and one that writes the time.

Comment: Sorry Sotirios , I thought I didn't explain it well and hence changed it. I don't have access to the java files and I received the service client project as a library. Is there a way to do it without annotating the fields as I don't have access to those elements?

Comment: @punter Yes, look into mixins.

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios. I'll have a look.

Comment: Excellent !! using setDateFormat() resolved my problem