# JSON Jackson ObjectMapper ReadValue - Error in converting date

Tags: java, json, jackson, spring-boot

I am seeing the error listed below when trying to convert the json string to an object.  I don't have the source code for Data class & it is part of a jar file. Is there a way I could use mixins to get this fixed?

**CODE**

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.readValue(request, Data.class);
```

**ERROR**

> org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct
>   instance of javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar from String value
>   '10:00:00': not a valid representation (error: Can not parse date
>   "10:00:00": not compatible with any of standard forms
>   ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE,
>   dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))

**JSON REQUEST**

```
 "timeSlot":{  
       "date":"2015-10-21",
       "endTime":"10:00:00",
       "startTime":"08:00:00",   
 }
```

**EDIT**

This issue is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020144/retain-xmlgregoriancalendar-date-format-after-converting-to-json-jackson-lib) , however this is occuring while deserializing. The other solution helped in appropriately serializing the request.

I have pasted the sample code which is not working below -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class TestJSONDeserialize {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Data.class, MyMixin.class);

        String jsonString = "{\"date\":\"2014-02-10\",\"time\":\"16:15:00\"}";
        try {
            mapper.readValue(jsonString, Data.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

**Data class (I cannot make changes to this file)**

```
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

public class Data {

    private XMLGregorianCalendar date;
    private XMLGregorianCalendar time;

    public XMLGregorianCalendar getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
    public XMLGregorianCalendar getTime() {
        return time;
    }
    public void setTime(XMLGregorianCalendar time) {
        this.time = time;
    }



}
```

I see the below error when I run this :

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not
>   construct instance of javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar from
>   String value '16:15:00': not a valid representation (error: Failed to
>   parse Date value '16:15:00': Can not parse date "16:15:00": not
>   compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
>   "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz",
>   "yyyy-MM-dd"))  at [Source: {"date":"2014-02-10","time":"16:15:00"};
>   line: 1, column: 21] (through reference chain:
>   com.comcast.json.test.Data["time"])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this done using custom deserializer and mixins. Code Below -

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConstants;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;

public class TestJSONDeserialize {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.addMixIn(Data.class, NewMixin.class);

        String jsonString = "{\"date\":\"2014-02-10\",\"time\":\"16:15:00\"}";
        Data data = null;
        try {
            data = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Data.class);
        } catch (JsonParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(data != null){
            System.out.println(" Data " + data.getDate());
            System.out.println(" Data " + data.getTime());
        }   
    }


}



import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class CustomDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<XMLGregorianCalendar> {

    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = 
      new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");


    @Override
    public XMLGregorianCalendar deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        try {

            GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
            c.setTime(formatter.parse(date));
            XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = null;
            try {
                date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
            } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return date2;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}




import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory;
import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;

public class CustomTimeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<XMLGregorianCalendar> {

    private static SimpleDateFormat formatter = 
      new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");


    @Override
    public XMLGregorianCalendar deserialize(JsonParser jsonparser, DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String date = jsonparser.getText();
        try {

            GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
            c.setTime(formatter.parse(date));
            XMLGregorianCalendar date2 = null;
            try {
                date2 = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(c);
            } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return date2;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}



import javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;

abstract class NewMixin {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
    public abstract void setDate(XMLGregorianCalendar date);

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomTimeDeserializer.class)
    public abstract void setTime(XMLGregorianCalendar time);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

See [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFAQDateHandling). Stick a date formatter on your field:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="HH:mm:ss", timezone="CET")
private Date startTime;
```

Comment: Thank You. I don't have the java file with me but I am using a class that is part of a jar which was provided by different team. I wouldn't be able to modify the class containing this field. I also cannot set a generic date time format for the whole class because date is yyyy-MM-dd and time is hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 1):

Already answered in this old post, but hope this will be helpful for someone in future.

Specifying `DateFormat` in `ObjectMapper` solved my issue.

```
objectMapper.setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat(MY_FORMAT));
```